# Some sort of simple lookup function in R

Tags: r, lookup

Here we have a super simple question. Let's assume we have a certain amount of particles placed randomly in a water column. We have information on the depth of each particle (df) and we have a temperature profile of the water column (profile).

```
temp <- seq(4,20,by=(20-4)/90)
depth1 <- c(1:91)
profile <- data.frame(depth1, temp)

id <- c(1:182)
depth2 <- c(rep(5:45,3),50:91,1:17)
df <- data.frame(id, depth2)
```

What would be the easiest way to return the ambient temperature of a specific particle (e.g ID=13) at given depth? The output in this case should be `[1] 6.844444` because the temperature at 17 meters is 6.844444 as you can see in "profile". The return needs to be a single value and the command should be as short as possible. It's gonna used repeatedly in a function() then.

There must be a very simple solution by using [square brackets] or so...

Thanks for any help...

Robert

Comment: It isn't completely clear what your expected output would be.  for `df$ID == 13`, is the expected return 16.6222 (where `profile$depth1 = 72` where 72 is taken `df$depth2[df$ID == 13]`

Comment: `merge(df, profile, by.x = "depth2", by.y = "depth1")`

Comment: Was not that clever to use `runif()` in terms of a reproducible example. See edits, so we can talk about a more specific example. Should be clear now...

Comment: `merge()`is somehow what it makes for me @Roland. But it needs to be a single value (temperature) for an individual particle (id)...

Comment: Well, usually (if you need to do this more than once) it is more efficient to do this for all particle at once, but you could use `match`: `profile[match(df[id == 5, "depth2"], profile$depth1), "temp"]`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. Works also good for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten it further to

```
profile[df[df$id==13, "depth2"], "temp"]
```

The inner expression evaluates to the numeric value of `depth1`, rather than a logical vector.

Or even shorter if the target values are always at a known column index:

```
profile[df[df$id==13, 2], 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it by myself...

`profile[profile$depth1==df[df$id==13,"depth2"],"temp"]`

Thanks anyway,
Robert